# set permission(777) for all the files, subdirectories of a directory in python without any loop

Tags: python-2.7, permissions

I want to set permission (777) to my directory ( including all the files and subdirectories ) in one line, don't want to use any os.walk or for loop

Answer (score 0):

You can call subprocess and run normal system command from there:
did not test but I think this should work:
subprocess.call(["chmod", "-R 777 /PATH"])